How can I represent multiple inputs in observation space
I am getting this error:
"AssertionError: Unsupported structured space '<class 'gym.spaces.dict.Dict'>'"
and I am not able to figure out what this error is?
This is my code

self.action_space = spaces.Box(low=np.array([0.0, -1.0]), high=np.array([0.5, 1.0]), shape=(2,), dtype=np.float32)
self.observation_space = Dict({
'depth_image': spaces.Box(low=0, high=255, shape=(112, 112), dtype=np.uint8),
'yaw': spaces.Box(low=-np.pi, high=np.pi, shape=(1,), dtype=np.float32),
'previous_action': spaces.Box(low=-1, high=1, shape=(2,), dtype=np.float32),}
)

I want the solution for solving this issue
